# Real Analysis. Bounds, Infimum and Supremum

Tags: real-numbers

Given that $S=\left\{x \mid 4x^2 > x^3 + x\right\}$.

(1) Determine whether $S$ is bounded.

(2) Determine their supremum and infimum.

I divided the equation by $x$ to have a quadratic. 
Then my roots are in decimals doesn't look correct.

Thank you!

Comment: Try and edit your question such to include attempts at a solution or a particular concept that you find hard to grasp, or it will get closed for not respecting the policy of the site.

Comment: S is not bounded $$ x \to -\infty \\ 4x^2> x^3+x\\ +\infty > -\infty$$

Comment: $$4x^2>x^3+x\\x(4x-x^2-x) >0  $$

Comment: Khosrotash please explain further.  I don't understand you.

Comment: hint: LHS is $\geq 0$

Comment: To solve the inequality ,be sure that "x>0 " then divide by "x" ,but if you are not sure : you must solve it both , 1st by x>0 ,second by x<0

Comment: S={x|4x^2>x^3+x} include x=-1 ,-2, -3 ,-4.5 ,-6.56 ,-100 ,-10000,-10000000,...,-$\infty$

Answer (score 1):

$$
4x^2 > x^3 + x
$$
Dividing both sides by $x$ and getting $4x > x^2 + 1$ is **wrong**.  You can divide both sides by a positive number and do that, or by a negative number and get "$<$" instead of "$>$", but $x$ is sometimes positive and sometimes negative.

You have
\begin{align}
x^3 - 4x^2 + x < 0 \\[10pt]
x(x^2 - 4x+1) < 0 \\[10pt]
(x-0)\Big(x-(2-\sqrt 3)\Big)\Big(x-(2+\sqrt 3)\Big) < 0
\end{align}

Thus there are three places where the sign changes: $0$, $2-\sqrt 3$, and $2+\sqrt 3$.  They divide the line into four intervals:

- numbers less than $0$,
- numbers between $0$ and $2-\sqrt3$,
- numbers between $2-\sqrt3$ and $2+\sqrt 3$
- numbers bigger than $2+\sqrt3$.
- On the first interval, all three of the factors are negative so the product is negative.
- On the second interval, the first factor is positive and the other two are negative, so the product is positive.
- On the third interval, the first two factors are positive and the third is negative, so the product is negative.
- On the fourth interval, all three factors are positive, so the product is positive.

So $S= (-\infty,0)\cup(2-\sqrt 3,\  2+\sqrt 3)$, and from that you get the infimum and supremum.

Comment: Thanks so much. So S is Unbounded and the
 Infrimum is 2-sqrt(3)
 Supremum is 2+sqrt(3)

Comment: The infimum is $-\infty$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Then the Supremum is 0.
So Unbounded sets can have Supremum and Infrimum?

Comment: The supremum is $2+\sqrt 3$.  An unbounded set has a supremum and an infimum within the ordered set $[-\infty,+\infty]$, but lacks either a supremum or an infimum within the set $(-\infty,+\infty)$.  If you think the supremum is $0$, then you're confused about something, but I can't say what unless I know how you reached that conclusion. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

1) $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} : x < 0 \Rightarrow x \in S$ (Why?).

So $S$ can't be bounded.

2) Can you figure it out yourself now?

Comment: No I still don't get it.

Comment: Be a little more specific please. Do you understand 1)?

Comment: Did you try something like: Let $f(x)=4x^2-x^3+x$....?

Comment: Do the numbers $-1,-2,-3,\cdots $ satisfy the inequality?

Comment: Yes they satisfy

Comment: Does -10000 satisfy the inequality?

Comment: Again, what exactly is it that you don't understand?

Comment: 1000 doesn't satisfy the inequality

Comment: Sorry I think this is useless. Bye